# Can someone please show me how to answer this question?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be random variables with $X_i < \infty$ and suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n>1)< \infty$. Compute $$P\left(\sup_n X_n< \infty\right).$$

I know I need to show that the event {Xn > 1} occurs for only finitely many n but I don't know how to so can someone please show me how to.

Thanks

Comment: Try Borel-Cantelli.

Answer (score 0):

By [the Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Statement_of_lemma_for_probability_spaces),
$$
P(X_n>1\text{ infinitely often})=0
$$
since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n>1)<\infty$. That is, $X_n>1$ occurs for only finite number of times almost surely. The number of times $X_n>1$ is random, but it is finite almost surely. So there exists a random index $N$ after which $X_n\le1$. It follows that
$$
P(\sup_nX_n<\infty)=P(\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_N,1\}<\infty)=1
$$
since $P(X_n<\infty)=1$ for each $n\ge1$ (you meant $P(X_i<\infty)=1$ instead of $X_i<\infty$, right?).